# How can we run multiple URLs at a time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I Have a scenario where I'm performing searches for products. Steps are Home_Page, Login_Page, Product_Search_Click, Product_Input, logout.
I want to run this script with 2 URLs and those are **qa1.abc.com** and **qa2.abc.com**.
I have designed by script using Correlation with the help of regular expressions.
How can I run my script with above mentioned URLs at a time. Suggested the best possible way with screenshots (if any). Let me know if anything needed from my end.

[URLs_CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LrEm.png), [Thread_Group_Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7YU.png), [CSV_With_User_Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4GzA.png), [Server_Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUtdi.png), [Users_Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMlGt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is go for the [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your tests as:

1. Taurus has capability of [running existing JMeter files](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)
2. Taurus can [pass the variables to the JMeter file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables)
   [3. Taurus can kick off multiple JMeter tests in parallel](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)

So given you come up with a [Taurus YAML config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file like this:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    variables:
      URL: qa1.abc.com
    script: test.jmx
- scenario:
    variables:
      URL: qa2.abc.com
    script: test.jmx
```

And specify the `URL` variable in your JMeter script like this:

[image]

It will be enough to launch Taurus as:

```
bzt your_config_file.yaml
```

and it will kick off both JMeter tests against different URLs at the same time

Answer (score -1):

There could be a number of solutions for this. One quick solution is with a [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) Pre-Processor. Define the variable `server` and add the two URLs in the values fields as shown below.

[image]

They replace the server in HTTP Default or in the HTTP Request sampler with `${server}`

[image]

[Sample JMX](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Examples/blob/master/variables/TestPlan-Exampes-DifferentURLs.jmx) is available on GitHub

Comment: Thanks Janesh, But seems like it's not working. I tried it by setting variable name and users under *user parameters*. Is there any other way to work on this, please suggest.

Comment: This should work as I checked before the post. Can you check if you have any spaces around the variables. Also, they are case-sensitive. You could include the URLs in a text file in rows and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element to read the URLs into a variable `server` and use them within the requests `${server}`

Comment: I tried with csv data set config, still it's taking only the single URL. Could you please check attached CSV, Thread group images and confirm is there anything that I missed.

Comment: Settings seem to be okay. Can you include the CSV file too? Do you have any blank lines in the test data file?

Comment: No Janesh, I don't have any spaces in test data file. Attached "Server_Details, Users_Capture" for reference. Please check once and confirm.

Comment: Can you share the sample JMX with the test data files without any confidential info?

Comment: Here is a sample JMX.https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-JMeter-Examples/blob/master/variables/TestPlan-Exampes-DifferentURLs.jmx